# CSS Clip - Allow background to show through

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply css clip to an element to allow the layer behind to show through. I have the following layout..

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.container {
background:lightgray;
}

.clip {
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100px;
  clip: rect(10px, 100px, 100px, 100px);
}

.section1, .section2 {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.section_left_red {
  height:100%;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
}

.section_left_blue {
  height:100%;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="clip">
</div>

<div class="section1">
<div class="section_left_red">
</div>
<div>

<div class="section2">
<div class="section_left_blue">
</div>
<div>

</div>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this..

[image]

So as I scroll down, the blue background then shows through. Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, resp. what you would actually _want_ to see here, with this given example.

Comment: I am trying to overlay a fixed mask on the screen that only lets a portion of the underlying div show through

Comment: Disabling the clip property in Chrome dev tools changes absolutely zeropointzero in regard to the visual result, so even more unclear what you want to achieve by this, or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use multiple background to create this. The idea is to color only a part of the background making the remaining transparent:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clip {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:5px solid lightgray;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(lightgray,lightgray) right/50% 100%,
    linear-gradient(lightgray,lightgray) bottom/100% 80%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.section1,
.section2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.section2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="clip">
  </div>

  <div class="section1">
  </div>

  <div class="section2">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that clip is the technique that you'll need to achieve this.

Clip css property is meant cut off part of an image that is absolutely positioned. I don't think it's meant for other elements.

instead of clip, have you tried using gradients to create a hole inside? Or maybe even a border:

```
.clip {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   border-top: 10px solid #fff;
   border-left: 10px solid #fff;
   border-right: calc(100vw - 60px) solid #fff;
   border-bottom: calc(100vh - 60px) solid #fff;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```